# execute dex file in an android app

Tags: java, android, shell, dalvik, userid

background:I want to write an app that can transmit dex file to another phone and execute it.

this is what my app trying to do:

1.transmit the dex file.

after the transmit,the file attributions are:

```
-rw------- u0_a128 u0_a128 760....
```

2.execute it with the code:

```
 try{

                Process proc=null;
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dalvikvm -cp /data/data/com.ray.offload/Hello.dex hello.Hello");

                proc.waitFor();
                java.io.InputStream is=proc.getInputStream();
                byte b[]=new byte[is.available()];
                is.read(b,0,b.length);
                System.out.println(new String(b));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("Read has Exception", "e:" + e);
            }
        }
```

com.ray.offload is where my app installed.

when I run this funciton,the logcat only shows:

```
  E/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: created from interp,name=java.lang.ProcessManager
  E/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: calling run(),name=java.lang.ProcessManage
```

note:if I use adb to push the dex file to my phone,I can get "Hello world".
and the file attributions are:

```
 -rw-rw-rw- shell shell 760...
```

I'm wodering about if I should chmod of the dex file.

so I just put:

```
 Process p=null;
 p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /data/data/com.ray.offload/test/Hello.dex");
 p.waitFor();
```

before I use 'dalvikvm' to execute the dex file.but the file attribution did not change when I use adb 'll' to see it.
so I change the attribution derectly through adb shell.

```
chmod 777 Hello.dex
```

it does get changed.but the app still not work.
then the most strange thing comes:
after I use dalvikvm to execute the dex file directly through adb.my app also has 'Hello world' on my logcat.

it means my app must work afer I execute the ded file through adb shell.

I'm just confused about all these problem.
I'm wondering if the 'dalvikvm execution' is just in another 'sandbox' of android. there must bu something wrong with the previlege.I'm seeking for help.....

Comment: dexopt needs to run. Your app probably doesn't have permissions to create the ".odex" file.

Comment: @fadden is trere any corresponding permission in Manifest.permission I can get from?